# How to call a method from a mocked object when a method from another mock is called?

Tags: spring-boot, mocking, mockito

Given below is the structure of my project

```
class A{
    void methodA(){
        // Gets data from the DB
        // Processes the data
        // Sends the data via a kafka topic MyTopic
        kafka.send(topicName, data);
    }
}

class B{
    // methodB is listening to topic MyTopic
    void methodB(String data){
         
    }
}
```

I want to test this entire flow.
Using Mockito, is there a way to call methodB directly (bypassing kafka) when kafka.send is triggered in methodA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that I am understanding what you have mocked and what not but my approach would look like this:

```
@InjectMocks
private ClassA classA;

@Mock 
Kafka kafka

private String data = "someData";
private String topicName = "someTopicName";

@Test
void yourTestMethod() {
  B objectOfClassB = new B();
  
  when(kafka.send(any(), any()).thenAnswer(a -> {
    CustomObject data = (CustomObject) a.getArguments()[1]; // get the Data object 
    objectOfClassB.MethodB(data);
    return;
  });

  classA.methodA();

  Assertions.assertThat(objectOfClassB.getSomeAssertionValue()).isEqualTo(1);
}
```

ObjectB can obiously be a service spy or something else. It does not have to be instantiated by "new". Any Object reference given will do the trick.

Comment: But I don't want to hardcode the data. The data will be generated by `methodA()` in my example. Is there any way to tell `Mockito` to forward whatever has been received by `kafka.send()`?

Comment: Yes. I have modified my answer accordingly. You can tell Mockito to get the data by calling `a.getArguments()[1]` in the `thenAnswer(` Methode. The Array Parameter is for the number of the Argument. In your case 1 for "data" and 0 for "topicName"